# How do you talk in general chat?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the slash command to speak in General chat on Diablo 3?

Answer (score 6):

It's **/c** (for channel)

> */c Hello there.*

This, of course, requires you to actually be in the General channel. If you joined another channel the same command would let you speak there, and if you're not in a channel the command wouldn't work.

You can also press the Quick Chat button next to the chat box, or just hit the [tab] key with chat open, to choose where your messages will be sent.

Comment: Hitting the [tab] key with the message box open will also bring up a popup that lets you tab between chat channels

Answer (score 0):

As [Hex points out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/71313/21619) you can use /c or /csay in any chat channel to speak, once you have joined that channel.  You can check out a full list of chat commands [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Chat_Commands).

Blizz provided a helpful tutorial on joining chat channels [here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/error-3007) as part of a bug workaround.  The relevant portion of which is this :

[image: How to join general chat]

Do note that as of patch [v1.03](http://www.diablowiki.com/Diablo_III_Patches#Patch_1.0.3) (v.1.0.3.10057), chat settings are saved when you log out, so if you join General and log out, you'll re-join General the next time you log in.

> Chat settings and preferences will now be saved whenever you log out